# Click element and change the text inside (with jquery)

Tags: jquery

I use this function to load the div '.slide'.
I want to change the text inside open to close when clicking the div. I want to arrange this by Jquery. How is this done?

```
$("#slideopen").click(function () {
    var slide = $(".slide");
    if (!slide.data("loaded")) {
        slide.load("/v3/ajax/timeline.php?id=<?php echo $cam_id; ?>");
        slide.data("loaded", true);
    }
    slide.slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).html("Your text here.")
```

.html() gets the inner content of the specified element, and when supplied with a string, replaces the content with the argument. You can also insert HTML elements such as p and a.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#slideopen").click(function () {
   var slide = $(".slide");
   if (!slide.data("loaded")) {
      slide.load("/v3/ajax/timeline.php?id=<?php echo $cam_id; ?>");
      slide.data("loaded", true);
   }
   slide.slideToggle("slow");

   if (slide.is(':visible'))
       $(this).text('Close');
   else
       $(this).text('Open');
}
```

Comment: clicking will set the label to close. But clicking close will not set open

Comment: right, it should switch (maybe you need to change vice versa), because you using `slideToggle` whitch means that you open/close it.